# Null pointer exception using a BaseAdapter and ViewHolder

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception, baseadapter, android-viewholder

I get a NullPointerException at the line:

```
viewHolder.list_item_TextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_TextView);
```

The same app is running without any problems, if the `viewholder` is not implemented. I add the `viewHolder`, like I did in other apps before and they are running. Can't find the error.

```
public class lv_cb_db_ea_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

final private Context context;
private Cursor cursor;
private SQLiteDatabase database;


lv_cb_db_ea_Adapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, SQLiteDatabase database) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.database = database;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

// ########  here comes the NPE  #########
        viewHolder.list_item_TextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_TextView);
        viewHolder.list_item_Checkbox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem_CheckBox);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    viewHolder.list_item_TextView.setText("Some Text");
    viewHolder.list_item_Checkbox.setChecked(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("selected")) != 0);

    return convertView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox list_item_Checkbox;
    TextView list_item_TextView;
}
}
```

here's the xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/listItem_CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listItem_TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listItem_CheckBox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here's the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'android.widget.TextView ws.rtin.android.listviewexample.lv_cb_db_ea_Adapter$ViewHolder.list_item_TextView' on a null object reference
```

--- added database.java and listview.java ----

Because there are some answers (thanks for that), which does not fixed the problem, I post my whole app (only three small java-files and the xml). "lv_cb_db_ea" is the main-file in the manifest.

Here is my database.java

```
public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

database(Context context) {
    super(context, "database", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE country(" +
            "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "code varchar(3) not null," +
            "name varchar(30) not null," +
            "selected integer not null)"
    );

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('0','DK','Dänemark',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('1','F','Frankreich',1)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('2','B','Belgien',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('3','NL','Niederlande',1)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('4','D','Deutschland',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('6','TR','Türkei',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('8','S','Schweden',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('10','FN','Finnland',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('11','GR','Griechenland',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('12','A','Östereich',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('13','LIT','Litauen',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('14','PL','Polen',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('15','P','Portugal',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('16','I','Italien',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('17','GB','Groß Britannien',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('18','IRL','Irland',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('19','L','Luxemburg',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('20','E','Spanien',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('21','CH','Schweiz',0)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO country VALUES('22','CZ','Tschechien',0)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

and here is the listView ("MainActivity")

```
public class lv_cb_db_ea extends Activity {

private static SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // connect to database
    SQLiteOpenHelper database = new database(this);
    sqLiteDatabase = database.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = getDBContent();

    //create an ArrayAdapter by given database-cursor
    lv_cb_db_ea_Adapter itemAdapter = new lv_cb_db_ea_Adapter(this, cursor, sqLiteDatabase);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.main_ListView);
    listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String sToast = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItem_TextView)).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(lv_cb_db_ea.this,
                    "Clicked on Row: " + sToast,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void findSelected(View v) {
    StringBuilder sToast = new StringBuilder();
    sToast.append("You've selected...\n");
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM country WHERE selected", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        sToast.append("\n").append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sToast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    cursor.close();
}

// outsourcing query (for more complex queries (i.e. multiple tables))
public static Cursor getDBContent(){
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM country", null);
}
```

Comment: The error tells you that the variable `viewHolder` is null.

Comment: I know, that's why they call it null-pointer-exception :-). The question is: why is there a NPE at this place? On other apps this works (as I wrote above).

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the variable `viewHolder` is null. Take a look at this part of your code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

The problem is that a view's "tag" is a place to hold custom data. It will only have a value if you call `setTag()`. Since you just inflated a new layout, `getTag()` returns `null` because you haven't set it. Instead, you need to create a new `ViewHolder` and set it as the view's tag:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

Comment: See "user2260040". It's nearly the same answer. I posted now the whole app. viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); crashes, when scrolling down the list. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Martin So from what I understand, this solution solves the NPE that you are asking about and your app crashes for another reason. Since you get a crash when you are scrolling, I suspect the problem is after the `if...else` statement because the `else` is setting `viewHolder` to `null`. That issue should be solved by the last line of code in my question above. (It goes in the `if` branch.) If you still need help, post a new question with your updated code and the new error from your logcat.

Comment: @Martin See my edited answer that hopefully clarifies what you need to do to fix the current problem.

Comment: No, now everything is running perfectly, I was too blind, sorry. And many thanks for such a good help!

Answer (score 0):

`viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`

should be

```
viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
```

in the if part.

Comment: I tried this too, but then it crashes, when scrolling down (I tried many things, but can't mention all here, because it would bursts the comments). Thanks for the answer, but because it's not a valid solution, I have to vote it down.